# how to let Squid to bypass connections on high load

Tags: caching, squid, http-caching

I would like to run Squid on a system with limited physical memory. The system should ideally do no page swapping. AFAIK, there are two ways to achieve this:

1. Modify routine `storeDigestAddable()` ( in file `store_digest.c`) in conjunction with a trigger from `sbrk()` to stop caching files. In this case squid gracefully degrades to being just a proxy and does not do any caching. This saves us from memory bloat caused by caching of large files in memory.
2. Bypass new connections in conjunction with a trigger from `sbrk()`.

Both of these would require changing Squid code. Have you encountered/contemplated this issue? Is there a way to achieve this goal (no swapping and limited physical memory) by any other means? It will be great if you can point me to any Squid configuration parameter that may help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. Set cache_mem to the correct size and Squid will do the job for you, dropping objects when the size is reached. You can also reduce the size of your ondisk cache to reduce the size of cache metadata.